# Rails + bunny gem - no such file to load -- bunny

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, bundler, rabbitmq

I have a rails controller:

```
class Console::AccesorBillsController < ConsoleController
  ...
  def bill
    AcceccorBill.new.run

    render :nothing => true
  end
end
```

I create new model there and run a method with an example from bunny's page (http://rubybunny.info/articles/getting_started.html):

```
require "bunny"

class AcceccorBill
  def initialize()
  end

  def run
    conn = Bunny.new
    conn.start

    ch  = conn.create_channel
    x   = ch.fanout("nba.scores")

    ch.queue("joe",   :auto_delete => true).bind(x).subscribe do |delivery_info, metadata, payload|
      puts "#{payload} => joe"
    end

    ch.queue("aaron", :auto_delete => true).bind(x).subscribe do |delivery_info, metadata, payload|
      puts "#{payload} => aaron"
    end

    ch.queue("bob",   :auto_delete => true).bind(x).subscribe do |delivery_info, metadata, payload|
      puts "#{payload} => bob"
    end

    x.publish("BOS 101, NYK 89").publish("ORL 85, ALT 88")

    conn.close
  end
end
```

But i always get this error:

```
NameError - uninitialized constant AcceccorBill::Bunny:
  (gem) activesupport-3.1.12/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:507:in `load_missing_constant'
  (gem) activesupport-3.1.12/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:181:in `block in const_missing'
  (gem) activesupport-3.1.12/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:179:in `const_missing'
  (gem) rake-0.9.2.2/lib/rake/ext/module.rb:36:in `const_missing'
  app/ext/acceccor_bill.rb:6:in `initialize'
  app/controllers/console/accesor_bills_controller.rb:17:in `bill'
  (gem) actionpack-3.1.12/lib/action_controller/metal/implicit_render.rb:4:in `send_action'
  (gem) actionpack-3.1.12/lib/abstract_controller/base.rb:167:in `process_action'
  (gem) actionpack-3.1.12/lib/action_controller/metal/rendering.rb:10:in `process_action'
```

Does anyone know how to solve that?

P.S.: I installed gem via bundler and it looks like `require` doesn't work.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Solved it.

I forgot to require the [bundler](http://bundler.io/v1.3/bundler_setup.html). So i just added this in the begining of file:

```
require "bundler/setup"
require "bunny"
```

And that is all.

Comment: Every time `Console::AccesorBillsController.bill` is called, it creates a new `Bunny` connection. I think if the connection can be reused for pub/sub, it should be created only once. Did you refactor the code better? If so, I'd like to know how you did that. Thanks!

Comment: @philipjkim It was just an example to test that bunny works, nothing more.